# What is the life expectancy of a Wookiee?

Tags: star-wars

At lunch, my coworkers and I were discussing *The Force Awakens*, and started questioning Chewbacca's age.  A quick check of [Chewbacca's Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca#Biography) and it says he is possibly about 230 years old as of Episode VII.  Following the [Wookiee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wookiee) link on that page, Wookieepedia claims that they live to be 400 years old.

Do we know from canon what the average life expectancy of a Wookiee is?

Comment: All Wookies look same, so maybe the one we saw in The Force Awakens is the son of Chewbacca.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Perhaps, except in the second trailer Han says "Chewie, we're home."

Comment: An old man can be mistaken especially when people look same.

Comment: How can we speculate about Han's mental health based on his age, given the medical technology available, as well as not knowing the answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110205/are-the-humans-in-the-star-wars-galaxy-really-humans)?

Comment: According to the old SW: Databank "[Several hundred years](https://web.archive.org/web/20071126052439/http://www.starwars.com/databank/species/wookiee/?id=eu)"

Comment: According to [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/34850/31394), over 400 years.

Comment: @randal'thor The information from that answer is non-Disney canon, even if it is the same number.  Not sure it counts as a duplicate in that case.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: “All Wookies look same” Bro that’s so racist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the (full Disney Canon) sourcebook "[Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know: Journey to Star Wars: The Force Awakens](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1465437851)", the lifespan of the average Wookiee is **400 standard years**.

[image]

And in the (Disney Canon) junior novel "[Lost Stars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Stars)" we meet a Wookiee Starfreighter captain called Lohgarra who has evidently been economically active for at least 200 years:

> She said she needed people around her who could be trusted; privately,
>   Thane believed she was too trusting, but it was her ship and her
>   business. **She’d run a freighter for a couple of centuries without his
>   help, so he figured she could size people up well enough.**

---

For the record, this all ties up nicely with the [old Star Wars: Databank entry on Wookiees](https://web.archive.org/web/20071126052439/http://www.starwars.com/databank/species/wookiee/?id=eu) which indicated that their lifespan was "*Several hundred years*"

Answer (score -5):

Rumor suggests

> it may be around 230 years, based on a sample size of one.   Although, of course it may be a lot longer if we assume Chewbacca is typical yet doesn't die of natural causes, which also seems likely.