# Was any character alive during all of the Star Wars episodes from I to VII?

Tags: star-wars

Is there any character in the Star Wars universe who is known to have been born before Episode I and is known to still be alive in Episode VII?

Some of the main characters that I have already ruled out as possible answers are:

- Yoda, Darth Vader, Senator Palpatine, who all died in Episode VI.
- Luke and Leia Skywalker, who were both born in Episode III.
- Jar Jar Binks, whose fate has not been established by canon (his voice is heard at the end of the DVD release of Episode VI, but we don't know if he survived until Episode VII).
- R2-D2 and C-3PO, because droids are not lifeforms.

Comment: Sarlacc Pit.  Snoke.  Chewbacca (according to Legends).

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Caluan_Ematt

Comment: Just because they aren't organic lifeforms does not to me indicate they don't count as alive.  We shouldn't buy into organic oppression of non-organic life.

Comment: @pcurry Are you saying R2-D2 and C-3PO counts as non-organic life? I say no, since in episode IV we are told: "there's no life forms aboard" about an escape pod carrying R2-D2 and C-3PO.

Comment: Episode IV starts 32 years after Episode I. Harrison Ford played Han Solo around 33-34 years old. Isn't it reasonable to think that he's roughly as old as his character? If that's the case, he'd most certainly be on the list.

Comment: With more investigation, I found this: http://www.yodasdatapad.com/ages.html Most likely based on Legends rather than canon

Comment: @kasperd Right, but that was said by an Imperial officer.  The Empire is speciesist (the Emperor doesn't approve of non-humans), as well as being a police state. We don't agree with them that the Rebels are scum, or think that the Tarkin Doctrine is a good idea, or that Wookies are only good as slave labor.  That the rest of the setting also treats droids as things rather than people is also problematic, but at least the main characters DON'T behave that way.

Comment: With alive in episode vii do you mean the beginning of episode vii or the end?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire No, it is not reasonable to assume that the character is as old as the actor. It is very common for older actors to play younger characters. But there's another reason to believe Han Solo was born before Episode I. Time dilation. For each trip he took on the Kessel Run, 40 years would pass for everyone else while he would age only a day and a half. So for each trip he went on, we know he was born 40 years older than he appears. Just a single trip would put his birth before Episode I. But none of that matters for this question because he's not alive at the end of Episode VII.

Comment: @Nick The question is "who is alive during all episodes from I to VII", not "who is alive during the whole length of each episode from I to VII". But whatever, it was a long shot, hence the comment, not the full answer.

Comment: @IvoBeckers I mean any character alive at the end. If the character made an appearance in Episode VII and canon doesn't tell us whether they survived until the end of the episode, then assume they survived unless they were last seen in immediate danger.

Comment: `Jar Jar is heard at the end of Episode VI` -- [Oh god, it's real.](https://youtu.be/AiM5zEEI_Jo?t=64)

Comment: @MatthewRead *breathes-mechanically* NOOOOOOOOOOOOEEEEEEE!!!!!!!!

Comment: Can I argue that Yoda is still alive in the force? :)  Actually, I guess we don't have evidence of Yoda, but we do have Obi-Wan in VII... if he's capable of saying "Rey" then he's alive in some sense.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire other characters have been excluded who were killed in Episode VII, so the question is about characters that are still alive.

Comment: With a universe of billions of people, there sure are. Do you mean specifically narrowed down to people that are mentioned in Legends, main characters, characters from Disney canon?

Comment: @pcurry The discrimination against lifeforms based on whether they're organic is, of course, called organism.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**Maz Kanata** is [over a thousand years old](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/11/12/star-wars-force-awakens-lupita-nyongo-maz-kanata).

From the novelization:

> Han indicated the soaring walls now rising before them (...) "The
>   galaxy’s full of watering holes, but nothing like this place. It’s
>   been run by an old smuggler named Maz Kanata for a thousand years."

Visual Dictionary:

[image: Maz Kanata Entry]

Comment: Leader Snoke looks quite old as well.

Comment: What's the canonicity of this age?   Also, do we know for a fact that she survived the attack on her establishment?

Comment: Disney has confirmed Lupita Nyong’o in episode VIII, so the chances she has survived are good. http://consequenceofsound.net/2016/02/disney-confirms-cast-for-star-wars-episode-viii-principal-photography-begins-today/
  
Wish I had more information regarding Supreme Leader Snoke -- I'll take a look at the novelization tonight.

Comment: The novelisation has a line from Maz after the attack, sighing and promising to rebuild the castle

Comment: @ThePopMachine Should I update the question to try drawing a more clear line? I was considering something along the lines of: "Any character seen in episode 7 who wasn't in immediate life threatening danger the last time we saw them can be assumed to have survived." But I had the feeling that would be going over the top. I would consider Maz Kanata to be a relevant answer if her age checks out.

Comment: @kasperd:   The question is fine, I don't think we need to mince words too much.   Especially with that quote, the answer is canon.   It would just be nice if we had evidence she is still alive since it wouldn't be completely arbitrary to suspect she is dead.

Comment: Good thing Abrams confirmed her age, because at least in the film, that line could as well have been a hyperbole along the lines of "she's been running that place forever". (Well actually going by his quote it *is* a hyperbole, since he says she's only been running it for a century, but is a thousand years old.)

Comment: Got nothing about Leader Snoke, except that he looks quite old ("a pink, pale face so aged it verged on translucence" (...) "long since healed over, old cuts and wounds marred the chin and forehead" etc) and that he "watched the Galactic Empire rise, and then fall" (which bring us to episode 3 or 2)

Comment: Presumably the cook counts also, then.

Comment: The strange thing is that Snoke and Maz without goggles look quite similar?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen:   There is a minimum of one big reveal per Star Wars movie.    Perhaps Maz = Snoke is the big reveal for Star Wars IX.    **You heard it here first!**

Comment: @ThePopMachine We got a closer look on Snoke in episode VIII and up close he looks nothing like Maz.

Comment: @kasperd:   It was a joke.

Comment: @DavidBanner - It turns out that he's only a few decades old.

Answer (score 248):

Assuming you are talking about the main characters Chewbacca is alive througout 1 to 7 (Note he was born 200 years before the battle of Yavin an he is still alive by the end of Episode VII)

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34849/how-old-is-chewbacca

Comment: What is the canonicity of the claim that Chewbacca was born on that date?

Comment: You can see an adult Chewbacca at the end of episode III which makes him older (or at leas as old as) than Anakin at that point (and thus born before Anakin)

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba, Do we canonically know how Wookieees age?   I not really doubting this is true, but do we canonically know he is older than Anakin?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Chewbacca was in "Wookiee Hunt" from the Clone Wars series. While its hard to say, he certainly looks like an adult. Granted, that says nothing about the actual age at the time.

Comment: According to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110502/4295 (which quotes cannon) the lifespan of a wookie is 400 years. There's no canon reference that I know of about the actual "speed" of development from birth to adultship but occam´s razor would suggest it should be longer than humans and not shorter.

Comment: Do we have canon evidence that occam's razor exists in the Star Wars universe?

Comment: The canon book Smuggler's Run says that Chewbacca was 180 in the Clone Wars, so he was definitely alive during Episode I.

Comment: @Plutor I think it's known as Occam's Lightsaber in that universe, as it cuts through many things, but also burns the unwary wielder.

Comment: Here,  take a gold badge!   I get to give uptown upvote #100.

Comment: Occam's Razor is not as clumsy or random as Kant's Axe

Comment: @Nagora, And my axe!

Comment: IMO, this answer is better than the Maz Kanata, Gen Ackbar, or Sarlacc ones, not that they aren't all right, because Chewie actually appeared in five of the movie, rather than us just inferring that the character must have be alive.

Comment: @Plutor, coming back and reading this, it deserves the upvotes for sheer comedic value (questioning the canonicity of everything), but actually, I think it's far deeper than that.   It seems clear, we have ample evidence that the simplest explanation is usually **not** the true explanation in the GFFA.   I say that no, Occam's Lightsaber does not exist.

Answer (score 153):

## The Sarlacc

[image]

Regarding the Sarlacc in the a Pit of Carkoon on Tatooine,

> **C3PO:** In its belly, you will find a new definition of pain and suffering as you are slowly digested...over a thousand years.

From this, one can infer that the Sarlacc has been alive for quite some time before (and after) the events of the episodes.

According to the official Star Wars Card Trader app (iOS, produced by Topps Card Co. in 2015, licensed by Disney), the Sarlacc is over **30,000 years old** and is still alive at the time of *The Force Awakens*.

Comment: Hardly a character though...

Comment: @Richard : This is precisely the type of fun, lateral answer you would go for.

Comment: You might as well have added in the Millenium Falcon

Comment: @Richard : The Sarlacc is a life form, the Millennium Falcon is not.  I read the question carefully before chiming in.  :-)

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Exogorth

Comment: @Richard If it's a stretch to say that droids are ‘born’, I'd definitely say it's as stretchy as it gets to say that the Millennium Falcon was ever ‘born’ or ‘alive’. At least the Sarlacc is a living organism that was presumably actually born (or hatched) at some point and was actually alive.

Comment: In the Star Wars books, Boba Fett killed the Sarlac, before climbing out and escaping with Dengar.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen : Is that canon or Legends?  :-)

Comment: @praxis: It was in Tales of the Bounty Hunters by Kevin J. Anderson.

Comment: Well,  we really don't know it is still alive in VII.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : The licensed card trader app from 2015 that I refer to mentions something about the Sarlacc "still digesting its victims from ROTJ decades later"...

Comment: @Richard +1 to honor Praxis's excellent answer.  It was the first answer that came to my mind, though Praxis sniped this opportunity much, much more quickly than myself.  (And did a better job...)

Answer (score 148):

## Admiral Gial Ackbar

[image]

Akbar makes a short appearance in *Episode VII*, however he was already an Admiral in *Episode VI*. Plus he was a captain during the Clone Wars, meaning that he would have had to have been born prior to *Episode I*.

During the canon *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* CGI TV series, Captain Ackbar briefly served along side Anakin Skywalker.

[image]

Comment: +1. I thought about him too, but I couldn't remember if he was in any of the prequel trilogy films, or if the back story Wookieepedia has on him for the Clone Wars is purely Legends. Could you add a clarifying source on that bit?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet as the answer now shows, Clone Wars is canon and Ackbar appear in the show. :)

Comment: I wonder how far back we'd have to go to get to Ensign Ackbar.

Comment: Or if he was ever enlisted, Seaman Ackbar... @Crashworks

Comment: Don't vote for this answer:   it's a trap.

Comment: Akbar dies in the Last Jedi.

Comment: @Robbert are there spoiler tags for comments?  You should consider using them if there are

Answer (score 15):

Well it's getting more and more difficult to find any proven characters, but I'll throw in a few "reasonable" possibilities, at least trying to cover 6 out of the 7 episodes.

### Supreme Leader Snoke

[image: Snoke]

This villain from Episode 7 looks very old, if he is more than 62 years old then it means he was alive in Episode I.

### Nien Nunb

[image: Nien Nunb]

Nien Nunb is Lando's copilot. We can see him in Episodes VI, and 30 years later in Episode VII. If he was the same age as Lando, or older, he might have been alive in Episode I as well (see Lando below).

### Lando Calrissian

[image: Lando]
<sub>(source: [twimg.com](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/689285328616685568/Jn4EIBgr.jpg))</sub>

Lando is older than Han Solo, and according this [webpage](https://www.yodasdatapad.com/ages.html) was born in 31 BBY. I'm not sure how the webpage found that out. It might be possible that he was born during Episode 1.

He didn't die in the movies and appeared in many games of the extended universe after Episode 6, so he might still be alive in later episodes.

### Bib Fortuna

[image: Bib Fortuna]

Jabba's servant can be seen in Episode I and Episode VI. He does not die in episode VI. He might be still alive in Episode VII.

### Chirpa the Chief Ewok

[image: Chirpa]

According to canon information, he was the chief of Bright Tree Village on Endor for 42 seasons, which mean, on Endor's 402 orbital period, approximately 12 standard years, which means since 8 BBY.

If he was born after episode I (32 BBY), it means he became chief of his village at only 24 years old, which is possible but seems a bit young, when also considering the fact that after Episode VI he retires and leaves his place to his daughter Kneesaa. It would be a bit too young to retired before 36 years old wouldn't it ?

Source: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chirpa

### The Exogorth from Episode V

[image: exogorth]

The gigantic asteroid worm who nearly ate the Millennium Falcon in Episode sure looks more than 40 years old. He looks quite badass and I don't see why someone would explode his asteroid so he must have survived until the next saga ;)

Comment: According to wookiepedia, Bib Fortuna died in 4 ABY (Ep. VI): 
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bib_Fortuna .
The last image in his gallery in the Star Wars databank says that "Fortuna died when Jabba’s sail barge exploded"
http://www.starwars.com/databank/bib-fortuna-biography-gallery

Comment: @BrianHellekin I get your point and I also believe we will never see him again. *But* we don't see him die in the movies, which make it *possible* for him to come back in a later episode. The gallery photo does make it look like he was there with Jabba, but if you look at Jabba's death scene (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxMmw1uj19s) we don't see him anymore. Everyone is panicking, running around, maybe he escaped ! :)

Comment: @Nicomac, it seems that in Legends he in fact escaped death during the Jabba's barge explosion, trying to take over and rebuild Jabba's criminal empire. Anyway it's all according to Disney now, if they want him alive they can ^^

Comment: Snoke says he watched the rise and fall of the empire.  In an interview he was also described as ancient.  You're surely right that he was alive before episode 1.

Comment: Lando has been confirmed to be in the new movie, so he is still alive, apparently.

Comment: How accurate is that age table? Is it canon? By his appearance (as Denis Lawson who was about 30 at the time) Wedge Antilles seemed closer in age to Han or even Lando. He appears briefly in TROS, could therefore qualify, if barely.

Comment: Snoke isn't that old.

Comment: Bib Fortuna's a definite "No" at this point. Okay, an extremely probable "No;" Star Wars characters have survived worse.

Comment: I hate multi answer answers, because some are wrong and some are ok.

Answer (score 13):

## Chewbacca

We have a previous answer claiming this is the case,  but the canonicity of the aging of Wookiees and the age of Chewbacca himself were in question.

Well, as of the release of the second *Solo: A Star Wars Story* trailer the canonicity is undeniable.

Han expresses surprise:

> A hundred and ninety years old ?!  You look great!

thus making official that [Chewbacca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chewbacca) had been alive during every Star Wars movie,  up to and including *Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker*.  He was played by Peter Mayhew up to Episode VII and was played by Joonas Suotamo in Episodes VII - IX and *Solo: A Star Wars Story*.

Answer (score 8):

Considering genetics alone, there's also **Jango Fett**.  He was an adult in Episode II, so must have been born before Episode I, and was the genetic basis for all of the Clone Troopers.  As indicated in a conversation in Episode VII, at least some of the Storm Troopers are still clones.  Though clearly not all of them, as the only other one whose face we've ever seen is clearly not a clone of Jango Fett.

**Edit:**
Here's the conversation in question (forgot it was Kylo Ren in this scene):

> **GENERAL HUX:** Supreme Leader Snoke was explicit. Capture the droid if we can, but destroy it if we must.
>  **KYLO REN:** How capable are your soldiers, General?
>  **HUX:** I won't have you question my methods.
>  **KYLO:** They're obviously skilled at committing high treason. Perhaps Leader Snoke should consider using a clone army.
>  **HUX:** My men are exceptionally trained -- programmed from birth --
>  **KYLO:** Then they should have no problem retrieving the droid. Unharmed.
>  **HUX:** Careful, Ren. That your "personal interests" not interfere with orders from Leader Snoke.
>  **KYLO:** I want that map. For your sake, I suggest you get it.

So clearly Kylo Ren is saying that a clone army is available.  I doubt he's saying they could just whip one up in a couple of days.  They must have some already, just off doing other things.  (Whether they're still using Jango's DNA for this is unknown, but I don't see why they wouldn't if it was still available.)

Comment: What conversation in VII are you talking about? The only conversation I remember that mentions clones, when cross-referenced with novelisation, explicitly states that clones are NOT used in the First Order. Even if there are rare exceptions, we've nothing to suggest Fett clones are still in use, especially since there's no care to retain the Fett DNA ever since clone troopers were phased out of production by Palpatine. This also doesn't go into the philosophical debate of whether a clone and the original is the "same person", lol.

Comment: Also, it's Fett, Jango Fett.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - I don't have the script or the novelization available, but there was a conversation between Finn's former superior officer and another officer stating that she doesn't use clones because she considers them inferior, but it seems implied that her opinions are in the minority in that respect, thus other squadrons might still use them.  (I agree that it's iffy whether Jango and his clones can be considered the same person, I was just thinking outside the box a little bit.)

Comment: General Hux acknowledged the value of clones, but he consciously chose to stick by his philosophy of training troops from childhood, confident in the value of this approach. This philosophy was inculcated in him by his father, an Imperial Academy instructor who admired the clones he commanded during the Clone Wars and was disappointed by the quality of Imperial Stormtroopers.

Comment: Hux is one of the highest ranking officers in the First Order, titled General of the First Order, but I don't know if that means his military philosophy represents that of the First Order. It is within the First Order's available expertise to raise clones, but don't forget: A clone army is expensive.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman [ISMDB](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) has it.  I google one of the other movies if I forget the URL since searching the new one gives bad results.

Comment: @Trisped - Thanks, I added the relevant excerpt to the answer.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman IMO, the question of whether any Jango clones are around is moot, because each clone would be a distinct individual separate from the individual known as Jango. That each clone is his own separate person is obvious to you if you've ever met a pair of identical twins. The only difference between a clone and a twin is the method of conception.

Comment: Note that even if he DID want to bring the clones back, it doesn't mean they would be Clones of Jango, it could just as well mean start a whole new clone line

Comment: SPOILERS!!! USE THEM!

Comment: @Daniel - I tried.  Spoiler tags don't play nicely with newlines.  Apparently you have to use stupid hacky HTML to make it work.  (Anyhow, there's nothing seriously spoilery about this particular scene.)

Comment: hacky HTML is <strike>NOT</strike> DEFINITELY NOT stupid.

Comment: Unless it doesn't render...

Comment: But he dies in ep II. And it's not certain Boba was alive during ep I, so both don't live through all 7 movies.

Comment: @Kevin - The point was that Jango's genetic code lives on in the form of armies of clones.  Boba Fett is not relevant.  Even if he was alive in Ep. I, he almost certainly died in Ep. VI, and unlike his father was not cloned as far as we know.  But Jango (in the form of one ore more clones) is potentially still alive, "from a certain point of view", if you will.

Answer (score 6):

Death seems a fluid concept when it comes to the Force.

Anakin "died" in Episode III (according to Kenobi), but we know he lived on as Darth Vader.  Is that a death or not?  Would you say that Anakin is in Episodes I through VI?

Kenobi "died" in Episode IV and Yoda in Episode V, but both have an active influence in subsequent events.  Kenobi urges Luke to trust his feelings.  Even in Episode VII, both of them speak to Rey in the visions she experiences when she touches Luke's lightsaber.

I know you said you ruled out Yoda, but I'd argue that both Kenobi and Yoda have a continuing active role, and clearly they were all alive since Episode I.

Comment: Anakin "dying" and "undying" isn't really a force thing - it was just a lie that Kenobi told Luke to protect him from the whole "your father" thing.

Comment: @David Grinberg:  Was it a lie?  Or did Kenobi truly believe that the life force that was Anakin ceased to exist when he gave himself fully to the Dark Side?  The original trilogy is a saga of redemption and perhaps resurrection.  At the end of _Jedi_, Vader is dead and Anakin lives again (at least in the sense that Yoda and Kenobi do).  [It's interesting to me that Kenobi has tremendous effects on the course of events by "talking" to Luke after he "dies."  If Anakin were redeemed, why doesn't his ghost contact Force-savvy characters in Episode VII?]

Comment: Nope. It was just a lie, solely to protect Luke from the truth.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - Why didn't ghost-Anikin appear in VII?  Because Sebastian Shaw is dead and nobody wanted to see Hayden Christensen in the movie.  (Also, if he was going to appear for anyone, it'd be Luke, and he's barely in the movie - maybe he'll show up in VIII?)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Qui-gon learned how to communicate with Yoda after his death, Yoda explicitly states this to Obi-wan and instructs him to learn the same. That is the reason Obi-wan and Yoda can guide Luke and Rey, but Anakin can't. He just never learned how, and it's too late now (this seems like something you learn **before** dying).

Answer (score 6):

In *The Rise of Skywalker* (Episode IX),

> Palpatine

whom we saw in Ep. I, is actually still alive, despite his apparent death that you mention. So, this is one additional character who has survived not only I-VII, but I-IX.

Answer (score 2):

**Mon Mothma**

She is in an deleted scene from Ep3, founding the rebellion and she died in Ep7 with the destruction of Hosnian Prime.

Comment: Interesting. If you look at the [Wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mon_Mothma), it references some canon sources that might establish Mon Mothma as having lived past the fall of the Empire. But are we sure she was in the Hosnian system when it was destroyed?

Comment: Not until we see the body; and in case of Star Wars, being blown up or body being in pieces _still_ doesn’t prove death.

Answer (score 2):

While this answer contradicts the original question,

### Emperor Palpatine (Darth Sidious)

In making the statement “Some of the main characters that I have already ruled out as possible answers are: Yoda, Darth Vader, Senator Palpatine, who all died in Episode VI,” the original  question has been revealed to be incorrect.

Senator (Emperor) Palpatine fulfills the question’s criteria:
“Is there any character in the Star Wars universe who is known to have been born before Episode I and is known to still be alive in Episode VII?”

Palpatine finally dies in *Star Wars Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker*. We learn that reports of his *Episode VI* death were premature, and he survived by inhabiting clone bodies.

Comment: He died and was reborn.

Comment: @Valorum Note the specific question asked: “ “Is there any character in the Star Wars universe who is known to have been born before Episode I and is known to still be alive in Episode VII.” Palpatine still fulfills this even if one considers him dying in Episode VI and being “reborn” prior to Episode IX. 

Answer (score 1):

Han Solo (maybe). He was born around the same year as Episode 1 takes place (32 BBY) so, depending on when exactly his birthday is, could count.

Answer (score -8):

How about Bail Organa? He's about the same age as Obi Wan but never died in the movies.

Comment: It seems unlikely that he would have survived Alderaan.

Comment: According to the [Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/bail-organa) (Disney's online encyclopedia for Star Wars): *Bail died when the Death Star destroyed his homeworld.*