# Does any character make an appearance during all episodes I-VII?

Tags: star-wars

Building off of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120666/was-any-character-alive-during-all-of-the-star-wars-episodes-from-i-to-vii) great question, does any character both survive and make an appearance in all seven Star Wars episodes? For example, we know that Chewbacca is certainly alive for the entire time, but he doesn't show up in prequels 1 and 2. The only character that I can think of is R2D2, but I feel like there must be at least one more.

Comment: R2-D2 *and* C-3PO

Comment: @Richard That was not C3PO, this protocol droid had a *red* arm!

Comment: @Fatalize He mentions that his arm was shot off at one point.

Comment: @Fatalize - I suspect that Jar Jar Abrams used much the same argument to try to underpay Anthony Daniels.

Comment: One not mentioned would be Anakin (as a jedi in 1-3, sith in 4-6, and his helmet in 7)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Assuming you include droids then there are only two characters who appear in all seven films, **C-3PO** and **R2-D2**. **Obi-Wan Kenobi** also makes a [brief voice cameo](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-reveals-obi-wan-and-yoda-are-star-wars-force-awakens) during Rey's flashback bringing the total to three.

The actor [**Sheb Wooley**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheb_Wooley) has voice cameo appearances in all 7 films and we also see Anakin's [fancy hat](http://www.starwarshelmets.com/vadrotj.jpg) in the the latest film, but the general impression is that it's empty.

---

Out of universe, Anthony Daniels is the only actor who has actually *acted* in all seven films.

Comment: The fancy hat was not in I & II.

Comment: Maybe link the question about which actor appeared in all/most SW films.

Comment: @Wikis no, but the wearer was.

Comment: +1 for fancy hat. I will always see it slightly differently now.

Comment: Richard coming through again, accepted.

Comment: Wait, but Anakin's fancy hat doesn't appear in episodes 1 or 2? Unless I'm remembering it wrong.

Comment: @DJMcGoathem It seems you are correct, unless you include the rather overt attempts at forshadowing when Anakin is leaving home in ep. 1 or hugging Padmé in ep. 2

Comment: 1138 / "I have a bad feeling about this" :)

Comment: @DavidBanner Where was 1138 in TFA? I noticed 2187 but not that.

Comment: @Milo Price I don't know (only watched the movie two times), but Hidalgo confirmed there is one: http://www.theforce.net/story/front/1138_Easter_Egg_Confirmed_In_The_Force_Awakens_167469.asp

Comment: I'm pretty sure Vader's helmet was not empty in episode 7, but in fact that is Anakin's skull. http://screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Star-Wars-7-Trailer-3-Darth-Vader-Helmet.jpg

Comment: It might be worth adding Kenny Baker to your out-of-universe list. He's credited in all 7 films as R2-D2 but I'm not sure how much screen time he gets in TFA.

Answer (score 11):

Obi-Wan Kenobi

He appears alive in Episodes I-IV, as a Force ghost in Episodes V and VI, and he appears vocally in a vision had by Rey when she grasps the Skywalker lightsaber.

Comment: One answer per answer, particularly if you don't want people downvoting overall for the iffy part.

Answer (score 0):

Separately, I would also suggest the Force as a character:

- Qui-Gon Jin tells Obi-Wan to be mindful of the *living Force*.
- Also, Yoda refers to the Dark Side of the Force as being *seductive*.
- Episode VII is The Force *Awakens*, which implies awareness.

And the one not like the others: The Force is Anakin Skywalker's father.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker

Comment: It's an energy field.

Comment: @Richard an energy field that is capable of intentional action, including seduction.  Seems like a non-corporeal entity to me.  Though, I guess I could just take refuge in the Legends continuity, and reference the West End Games rules for the Dark Side being specifically sentient.

Comment: I think "seductive" is linguistic personification, not literal personification. Many things that are clearly not living entities are described as "seductive". Examples: "The Seductive Ideology of Craft" [Source](http://www.justmeans.com/article/trim-tab-magazine-the-seductive-ideology-of-craft), *Three Seductive Ideas* (book title) [Source](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674001978&content=reviews), *Seductive Poison* (book title) [Source](http://www.amazon.com/Seductive-Poison-Jonestown-Survivors-Peoples/dp/0385489846)

Comment: @pcurry A chocolate cake could be described as seductive, or a factory of robots could be described as waking when they are turned on.  Also, a 'character' in a story doesn't actually need to be alive to play a significant part; look at Wilson in Castaway.

Comment: There's some credence, though. Yoda and others refer to the Force constantly as a guide and ally. [The Father](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)) even tells Obi-Wan of "letting the will of the Force take shape." Qui-gon advises Obi-Wan to "be mindful of the living Force." It may be an energy field, but the Force is constantly being given characteristics to the point where it's not clear if it may or may not be alive and/or intelligent.

Comment: In general some Jedi treat the Force as a living entity. These are generally more powerful (Yoda, Obi-Wan). Others, usually the Dark Side or those weaker/ more open do the dark side, treat the Force as a tool. For example (Anakin, The Emperor,)

Comment: @Richard oh, also, force impregnation of Shmee Skywalker

Comment: I am not stating that the force is God, but this is a bit like saying that God appears as a character in all movies containing christians, provided that the christians *say* that God is an aware, active agent. Basically just comes down to what you consider to be a character: naturally if X is to be considered a character and X is omnipresent, then X is in all the movies :-) I don't think there's any doubt that the force really exists or that (e.g.) Yoda believes it to have some kind of intentions. Whether this is canonically just his opinion about a possibly-impersonal force, I don't know.

Comment: @SteveJessop If God were actively visibly miracle-ing things in the source, I'd probably say God had appeared in that source.