# How old is Chewie?

Tags: age, friday-the-13th

Chewie was a friend of one of the protagonists. He loved partying. Chewie had what was possibly a long friendship until

> the bad guy killed someone

during one of the most violent scenes in the movie.

### How old was Chewie in Friday the 13th?

<sub>Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114983/how-old-is-finn).</sub>

Comment: Not related, not a dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34849/how-old-is-chewbacca

Comment: @NKCampbell : These questions are part of a theme (How old Is Finn?  How old is Rey? etc.)  I've rolled back your edit of the title to preserve this.

Comment: @Praxis - I get it but the joke is coming at the expense of the legitimate purpose of this site. I'm all fine and dandy with comic relief but the title is deliberately misleading and should be edited

Comment: @NKCampbell : I rolled back on the basis of conflicting with author intent, since the author's purpose for posting the question was the title itself --- at least, that's what I assume.  But I'm not the author of any of these questions.  Most (but not all) are by ibid.  Another (the Mace one) is by randal'thor, and the one about Finn is by another user.  I understand your reason, but you might want to discuss it with them and/or open a case on meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Mid-30s

Unfortunately, we can't be precise.  The film doesn't mention the ages of any of the characters, and the script, casting indications, and interviews are unhelpful.  Also, the film has no novelization.

But we can reason that Chewie is in his **mid-30s**, in the following way:

- the characters are friends who all appear to be of a similar age
- the film is set in 2009
- the film starts with a flashback to 1980 where Jason witnesses his mother's death; Jason is probably less than 10 at this time

A time difference of 29 years added to Jason's initial age would make Chewie somewhere between 35 and 40.

None of them appears to be 40, however, so I'll settle on **mid-30s**.